# How to generate extent report if test case failed in between

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I recently started using Extent report in selenium webDriver. I have created a project which contains 20 test cases. Every test cases is written in separate method which I am calling one by one from a different class. I am calling Extent report in browser at the end after all test cases are done running successfully.
But now I am facing problem. If because of some issues like network error or delay in response from server or Element not found Exception my test cases are getting failed in between somewhere. And I am not able to generate report.

Please tell me how to overcome this problem. I want my report to be get generated even if my test case fail in between. Report should tell where it is failed and how many test cases executed successfully.

NOTE: I am not using Testng framework.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Extent report is best report for tesng framework. If you are not using it. Then you can use it with try catch block.

Comment: Thank you @Murthi. Yes, try catch block is working but I was just not sure whether it will work for all exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use try-catch block to handle exceptions.

Then call extent report in the catch block.

Sample Code:

```
try{

// Your Code

}
catch(Exception e){

    test.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Error");

    extent.endTest(test);   

    extent.flush();

    driver.get("C:\\Project\\file.html"); 

}
```